# Bootstrap 5 (beta) - Navbar partial Override - Sticky Top Not Working

Tags: navbar, sticky, bootstrap-5

I'm using the BS5 beta and I'm running into an odd problem with the sticky-top class - I'm relatively new to Bootstrap.

**USE CASE**

1. I want to customize the .navbar (and dependent classes). I created a complete copy of the navbar partial (not sure if this a best or bad practice, but I have too many changes to do it piecemeal.
2. I want to use the sticky-top class (the fixed-top class has the same problem)

**IMPLEMENTATION**

1. The custom navbar partial is imported after the off-the-shelf navbar partial.
2. Most of the other overrides are working fine.

**ISSUES**
Sticky-top only works if either:

- I don't use a custom navbar partial - but obviously I don't want to modify the off-the-shelf partial.
- I use a custom partial and hard-code the .navbar class position property to sticky (from relative).

So, I can make it work by hard-coding the position property - not the end of the world. But it seems to me that if sticky-top works with the off-the-shelf partial, it should work with the custom version. And I'd like to avoid unnecessary customizations...

Is this a beta bug or am I doing sth really backwards?

```
  NAVBAR PARTIAL
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  // navbar position should be relative and
  // sticky-top helper class should force navbar to be sticky
  // this works with the off-the-shelf navbar partial, but not an overridden one
  **position: sticky;** // modified - 2021.02.25
  padding-top: $navbar-padding-y;
  padding-right: $navbar-padding-x; // default: null
  padding-bottom: $navbar-padding-y;
  padding-left: $navbar-padding-x; // default: null
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap; // allow us to do the line break for collapsing content
  justify-content: space-between; // space out brand from logo
  @include gradient-bg();


  POSITION PARTIAL (not modified)
  .fixed-top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: $zindex-fixed;
}


 NAV TAG
<!-- NAV BAR -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light navbar-expand-xl sticky-top">
  <div class="container-xl">
```

Comment: What's the point in using BS if you have to put in that much work to do something so easy? It's really not needed anymore.

Comment: I take it you never used Bootstrap...

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson I'm sure your perspectives would be instructive in a post on the pros and cons of BS. In the meantime, I'm still trying to resolve the issue in my original post.

Comment: Plenty of blog posts about it out there already, but setting that aside, since you're having an issue with a beta, you might want to review or post the issue on their git repo. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues